# how can I publish an android app with android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG?

Tags: android, restrict

I have an android app to analyse data of calls using android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG but I got no way to upload it how can I do this.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
```

Comment: How about searching the web for "how to upload an app to playstore"?

Comment: I already upload it but i got rejected message and try all i get to avoid this but no way

Comment: In this case maybe https://android.stackexchange.com/ is better suited for the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can upload an app with those permission and SMS permissions to the store anymore due to an update to the playstore an applications privacy policy . However, there are a few modifications you can make to your code which might allow ou to be able to push the application. Please see the materials below as reference:

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/reminder-smscall-log-policy-changes.html
https://proandroiddev.com/no-more-sms-call-log-permissions-now-what-9b8226de7827
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303

Comment: i'll do but what about new apps which request these permissions ?

Comment: i read references but i found nothing about code modification and what can i do